# 301 Redirect to new domain with some specific URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I saw similar topics but couldn't find a practical answer to my problem.

I'm moving my old website to a new one, and some URLs are changing.

I would like to make a generic 301 redirection to the new domain (because most paths are the same), while individually redirecting some URLs.

Here is what I have on my old website .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  Redirect 301 "/custom/url/" "https://new.com/my-custom-url"
</IfModule>
```

But the 301 redirects to : **https://new.com/custom/url** instead of **https://new.com/my-custom-url**

Some of my URLs also have URL parameters I would like to redirect, such as :

```
Redirect 301 "/brand.php?name=Example" "https://new.com/Example"
Redirect 301 "/brand.php?name=Example2" "https://new.com/another/url"
```

which do not seem to work as well.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the 301 redirects to : `https://new.com/custom/url` instead of `https://new.com/my-custom-url`

It is because your specific redirect rule appears after generic one. Moreover you are mixing mod_rewrite rules with mod_alias rules and these are invoked at different times.

Have it like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# redirect /brand.php?name=Example2 to new.com/another/Example2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(Example2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^brand\.php$ https://new.com/another/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# redirect /brand.php?name=Example3 to new.com/category/Example3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(Example3) [NC]
RewriteRule ^brand\.php$ https://new.com/category/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# generic redirect /brand.php?name=Example to new.com/Example2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^brand\.php$ https://new.com/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# redirect custom URL
RewriteRule ^custom/url/ https://new.com/my-custom-url [R=301,L,NE,NC]

# redirect everything else
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's working, thank you.

 I have another question : How can I redirect the URL parameters individually, instead of a generic rule ? For example "old.com/brand.php?name=Example" to "new.com/brand/example" AND "old.com/brand.php?name=Example2" to "new.com/example2" ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to use this. I tried : 

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /brand\.php\?name=([mybrandname) [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^ https://new.com/brands/mybrandname [R=301,L,NE]`

Which returns a 500 error

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but every `brand.php?name=something` must be redirected to an individual URL. I'm not sure how to edit your example accordingly.

`brand.php?name=brand1` must be redirected to `new.com/product-category/brand1` and `brand.php?name=brand2` must be redirected to `new.com/brand2` (for example)

Comment: This `/product-category/` is new addition that wasn't covered in original requirement. Current rule is generic so `brand.php?name=anything` will be redirected to `new.com/anything`. Any specific cases you can tweak yourself by changing: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+) [NC]`

Comment: Check my updated answer now to see specific and generic redirect rules

Comment: It's perfect, thank you very much for your time and your help.